# Camel case labels on f.submit form buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a pretty standard Rails app with a standard form something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @foo_bar do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :some_fields %>  
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

It works as expected except that the labels on the buttons end up

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Foo bar">
```

or

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Foo bar">
```

The issue I have is the 'Foo bar'.  I know it's a camel case model class name issue.  I also know I can do something like:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="<%= action_name == 'new' ? 'Create' : 'Update' %> Foo">
```

or

```
<%= f.submit "#{action_name == 'new' ? 'Create' : 'Update'} Foo Bar" %>
```

But just wondering if there was a more elegant method I was missing?

Comment: why don't you use css ? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can send parameter when render partial with this form.

***new.html.erb***

```
<%= render 'form', button: 'Create'  %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form', button: 'Update' %>
```

***_form.htm.erb***

```
<%= simple_form_for @foo_bar do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :some_fields %>  
  <%= f.submit "#{button} Foo Bar" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I could do that but that then has custom code in 3 files vs the one just in the f.submit

Comment: what you want, but my example is recommended  in rails

Comment: agreed. The model for such things is that there is a there is a view for edit.html.erb, one for new.html.erb and both share the actual form elements in _form.html.erb. In the first two views, the form itself is pulled in by rendering it as a partial. Distinctions in behavior are triggered by values passed into the rendered partial.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact problem and it is much easier to fix than you think;

**For f.submit buttons you can just do:**

```
  <%= f.submit "Create Foo Bar" %>
```

**Or you can try this:**

```
<%= f.submit "create foo bar".titleize %>
```

**And for labels you can do:**

```
<%= f.label :create_foo_bar, "Create Foo Bar" %>
```

The first argument isn't meant to be the title as most people think. Rails expects the first argument to be the object name and thus it automatically makes it the title if you don't pass a second argument(option) with the real title.

Comment: I get that but I guess to clarify I was hoping there may be a way to just pass 'Foo Bar' or 'Bar' into the submit and it would add the 'Update' or 'Create' depending on the action.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah in that case i think the if else statement you did is pretty good. You can also put the ? : statement in your application_helper.rb inside a method and then just call the method in the view instead of the whole if else statement... that way the code in the view is a little bit cleaner.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing... I am guessing this is just a Rails quirk and not much way around it.  I guess I could delegate a class "Bar < FooBar" etc. but that is probably even more work than it's worth.  Rails should at least titleize the label by default.